# i got this error (mqtts server connection failure MqttException (0) - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: connection closed) mqtts connection

Tags: javascript, react-native, mqtt, iot

```
    MQTT.createClient({
        uri: 'mqtts://there is a host:8883',
        clientId: '',
        protocol: 'mqtts'
    }).then(function (client) {

        client.on('closed', function () {
            console.log('mqtt.event.closed');
        });

        client.on('error', function (msg) {
            console.log('mqtt.event.error', msg);
        });

        client.on('message', function (msg) {
            console.log('mqtt.event.message', msg);
        });
        client.on('connect', (msg) => {
            msg.reconnect = true
            console.log('connected');
            client.subscribe("here was a topic", 0);
        })

        client.connect((input) => {
            console.log('adjisioudjjh', input);
        });
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('error is from here', err);
    });
}
```

i am trying to build mqtts connection for a secured connection with server and i got this error, can't build connection, how to and where to upload private key, CA certificate, and also this library(sp-react-native-mqtt) doesn't support any type of certificate, please help me to find a library for this

Comment: Asking for software recommendations if off topic for Stack Overflow (that's what https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ is for)

Comment: We need a lot more information here, The error is from java (not javascript) so where exactly are you seeing the error, on the client side or the broker? Also more details about how the connection is secured, are you trying to setup a mutual TLS or just confirm the broker is who it claims to be? Is the broker using a certificate signed by a public CA or a privately issued one?

Comment: thanks for reply, i am trying mutual TLS, and i trying to build a connection Aws Iot.

Comment: before this mqtt i am using ( useEffect(() => {
    API.graphql(
        graphqlOperation(subscriptions.onUpdateDeviceData)
    ).subscribe({
        next: async ({ provider, value }) => {
            // console.log('this function called');
            let topic = "here is topic"
            let payload = await value?.data?.onUpdateDeviceData?.payload
            dispatch({
              type: actionTypes.SET_ALLDATA_PAYLOAD,
              payload: payload ,
            });
        },
        error: (error) => console.warn('error is error', error)
    },);
}, [])

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75432602/edit) the question, do not try and add code in comments.

Comment: can you provide me the better solution for AWS IOT connection